# How to get the user's details from amazon cognito post logging in?

Tags: boto3, amazon-cognito

Details about the setup:

1. I am setting up AWS cognito for a new user
2. I am able to send the user to the sign in page of the cognito
3. Once the user signs in, they are redirected to a URL that looks like http://localhost:5000/aws_cognito_redirect?code=667f8988-aabc-494e-a8b0-0dc0d47057ab

I need to use the code to get the information about the user's profile and such details.

How can I do it using boto3? I am not able to figure this out using the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exchange the code for tokens following the steps listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html). Once you have the tokens, you can decode the id token (can use pyjwt library) to get the details about the user.

Keep in mind that if you are using authorization code grant for security reasons to stop the tokens flying around in the front end, you should do the exchanging and decoding in the backend and then pass the details to the front end.